# Is an e-bike without pedals considered a bike? (in Europe)

Tags: regulations

I'm interested in ordering this product: [Smacircle S1: The eBike That Fits In Your Backpack](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/smacircle-s1-the-ebike-that-fits-in-your-backpack-bike--2/x/5980930#/). This link is **only for the purpose of explanation**.

I am trying to figure it out if in **Europe** (EU regulations) this will be considered an e-bike or a motorbike?

Specifically:

- the possibility of **bringing it on flight** (also in terms of battery)
- driving it **without helmet and/or license**
- other **regulations** involved

Answer (score 1):

To bring it on an Airline to Europe, the batteries Amp Rating times its Voltage may not exceed 100 (or with special permission, 160) or contain more than 2 grams of lithium ([source](https://www.easa.europa.eu/system/files/dfu/Background%20Information%20Lithium%20Batteries.pdf)). While I could not find detailed enough specs about the battery to for the bike to determine if it is the case, but it seems likely that it would fall afoul of the regulations. Do note that other regulations may apply based on where you are flying from, and Airlines might have their own restrictions.

The Bike seems to fall under the classification of a L1e-A vehicle ([source](http://www.bike-eu.com/laws-regulations/nieuws/2016/7/european-commission-confirmed-categorization-speed-e-bikes-10126788), exactly what applies will vary from country to country however. It is also not clear to me if you could just bring it, airline regulations aside, without that particular model having undergone a classification procedure in Europe.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I read the 2 sources you linked. However it's not very clear to me: say it actually falls within L1e-B , what are the requirements to drive it and / or bring it on board (on a plane)?